# FTP -> VSFTPD -> allow uploading folders

Tags: ftp, fedora, directory, vsftpd

I have a Fedora FTP server that uses VSFTPD. I wanted to know how I could allow the users to upload directories and make directories.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check your SELINUX settings. VSFTPD will allow this, it is probably SELINUX blocking this.

Here is a working config from RHEL5.

It will chroot users into their home directory and allow file/folder creation assuming they can authenticate by methods enabled in the systems pam configuration.

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=0072
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
ascii_upload_enable=YES
ascii_download_enable=YES
ftpd_banner=FTP server
ls_recurse_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
pasv_min_port=30000
pasv_max_port=60000
force_dot_files=YES
use_localtime=YES
```

With the above config you can then use /etc/hosts.allow to lock down vsftpd to certain remote users or allow ALL to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have

`write_enable=yes`

in your *vsftpd.conf*. It's off by default so by default your FTP site is a read-only site.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "the users", did you mean the local system users?  If so, you need the "`local_enable` line.  If you instead meant "the VSFTPD users", ignore it.

```
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES

# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
```

Comment: `local_enable=YES` is not related to the question

Comment: @gelraen: That's a matter of interpretation.  But OK, I've edited my answer to clarify.